# How to resolve `Multiple controls with the same ID 'Label1' were found. `?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create dynamic label's in my web form app when but seem to be getting this error

`Multiple controls with the same ID 'Label1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.'`

This is what I have:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Panel ID="OverViewUpdate" runat="server">
         <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And Code Behind:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
  {
     Label label = new Label();
     label.ID = "Label" + i.ToString();
     label.Text = "Label" + i;
     OverViewUpdate.Controls.Add(label);
  }
  ((Label)OverViewUpdate.FindControl("Label")).Text = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms") + "<br/>";
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: There must already be a label on the form called "Label1" *before* you add your labels in the loop. You'll need to find and rename it, or use a different prefix for your own labels.

Comment: And that's just it :-) I do not have label named "Lable1" anywhere on the form?

Comment: _"I do not have label named "Lable1" anywhere on the form"_ ... that you are aware of. But obviously, there has to be one.

Comment: Use something like `label.Text = "MyLabel" + i;`, then you won't have conflicts with the normal asp Control Naming.

Comment: Okay, so it I think I found the problem.  I am already giving the Label an ID `label.ID = "Label" + i.ToString();` and when removing that line it works, but the dynamic labels aren't displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as per comments, it seems perhaps that the page already has a control with that ID. The next problem, if you have to be sure you don't run that code each time - in other words, only add the controls on first page load - not each additional button click and post back.

eg like this:

```
if Not IsPostBack then
    ' code here to add those controls
End if
```

Remember, on each button click or anything that post's back the page, then all your code runs again - including the page load event. So for a "really" first page load, we check IsPostBack as per above.

However, for the most part, when we need repeating data or information, there no need to inject or to try and add controls by code. You can try doing this, but in the VAST majority of cases, you can use one of the built control's that allow you to do this is great ease, and in most cases without looping code either.

So, for some controls - that you want to repeat? Then use what is called a repeater.

For table like data? Then use a gridview, or say listview. And even better is those controls are data bound - and will fill out for you automatic, and do so without again without looping code.

So, say we want some text boxes to show a list of hotels we have. and MORE often then not, such repeating data comes from a database, which is even better yet.

So, we don't even have to know how many labels or text boxes we need ahead of time.

So, now our markup can be this:

[image]

And now, our code can be this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }
    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {

            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            MyGrid.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            MyGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And output:

[image]

so, you can see how we did not need to inject, or loop to inject or add controls to the web page, but used a repeating control.

But, in your case? I would make sure your code that adds the controls ONLY runs inside of the IsPostBack = false stub.

Answer (score 0):

It seems perhaps that the page already has a control with Label1.
in that case you can use the following statement inside loop.

```
label.ID = "Label" + i+1.ToString();
```